# 500: not-uuid type instead of 404

Tags: typescript, postgresql, backend, nestjs, typeorm

(I'm a newbie in this)
I'm using nestjs+typeorm+postgres for my app. There is a "community" column in the db, which uses UUID type as id.
So in my app, I have written a basic logic to find out the exact community from the given query ID and returns 404 if not found, but if I send non-UUID type in my request URL, it's throwing 500 saying non-UUID type and the app is crashing.
Why I'm not getting proper 404?
I did try and catch to avoid the app crashing but there should be a way to return proper 404.

My Community.service.ts file (needed part):

```
// GET: gets the specified community if id provided in
  // query, otherwise returns all communities
  public async getCommunity(id?: string): Promise<Community | Community[]> {
    if (!id) {
      const communities = await this.communityRepository.find();
      return communities;
    } else {
      const community = this.communityRepository.findOne(id);
      return community;
    }
  }
```

and here's community.controller.ts (needed part):

```
@Get('')
  async getAllCommunities(
    @Query('id') id?: string,
  ): Promise<Community[] | Community> {
    try {
      const communities = await this.communityService.getCommunity(id);
      if (!communities) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
      }
      return communities;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  }
```

Comment: First of all you are missing ```await``` from ```this.communityRepository.findOne(id);```.
I suggest you to install [```class-validator```](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) and use the ```isUUID()``` validator if the ```id``` is not *undefined*.
Doing this you can check that the id is a valid UUID, if not throw an error.

Comment: thanks [CarloCorradini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6676781/carlo-corradini) I had already class-validator installed but wasn't aware of UUID checking

Comment: Nice, Add it to the answer?

Comment: sure [Carlo Corradini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6676781/carlo-corradini)

Comment: [This is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73814020/param-wont-cast-to-dto-type-in-nestjs-when-trying-to-use-class-validators) like this, which can be follow to solve this exact part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to install [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) and use the `isUUID(id)` validator if the `id` is defined.
Doing this you can check that the id is a valid UUID, if not throw an error.

Example:

```js
@Get('')
async getAllCommunities(
  @Query('id') id?: string,
): Promise<Community[] | Community> {
  // If 'id' is defined check if it's a valid UUID format
  if(id && !isUUID(id)) throw new Error(`Invalid id, UUID format expected but received ${id}`);

  try {
    const communities = await this.communityService.getCommunity(id);
    if (!communities) throw new NotFoundException();
    return communities;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```