# Param won't cast to DTO type in NestJS when trying to use class validators

Tags: typescript, error-handling, nestjs, class-validator, nestjs-swagger

I'm trying to add validation to the param I get in the request for example to delete something. The param is a string but it has to be a valid UUID. I added the dto to the type of the param in the controller.

```
@Delete(':personId')
  async deletePersonIdentity(@Param('personId') id:deletePersonIdentityDto) {
    return this.personIdentityService.deletePersonIdentity(id.personId);
  }
```

The DTO for deletePersonIdentity looks like this.

```
export class deletePersonIdentityDto {  
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'fd914b72-a423-4256-99a1-aff78da9281f',
    description: `ID of the Person`,
    required: true,
  })
  @IsUUID()
  readonly personId: string;
}
```

Even if I pass a valid UUID in the param I still get a bad request that says that the id must be a UUID. This is the error thrown by the class-validator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `req.params['personId']` (what `@Param('personId')` maps to) does not satisfy the type `deletePersonIdentityDto`. What you're looking for is `@Param() { personid }: deletePersonIdeentiyDto` which is equivalent to `const { personId } = req.params`